# Where cudaWaitExternalSemaphoresAsync_v2 comes from

Tags: cuda

I wrote a code with CUDA 11.1 on my local machine and everything is built ok.
But trying to built it on a far machine, I get the link error

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cudaWaitExternalSemaphoresAsync_v2

The strange thing is that I use cudaWaitExternalSemaphoresAsync in my code and not cudaWaitExternalSemaphoresAsync_v2.
In addition, there is no cudaWaitExternalSemaphoresAsync_v2 in the cuda declarations , not 11.1 and not in other version , so from where this symbol comes from ?

Comment: It is an internal implementation of the `cudaWaitExternalSemaphoresAsync`. It should be in the CUDA runtime library. If you have an runtime library available, it is likely too old and not matching the version you linked against

Comment: @talonmies - I will clarify my miss understanding. When the project is built (compiled and linked) on the far machine, it uses bins and h files that are taken from CUDA Toolkit that is installed on that far machine. So it seems the compiling and linking are of the same version that exist there and should be ok, isn't it?

Comment: The compilation environment on the far machine is broken.  In what way I cannot say based on the information provided here.  You might simply have an improperly set up project on the far machine. For example a project file that specifies the proper include path but an improper link library path.  You might also have missing files, a corrupted CUDA install, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The given comments lead me to check installation of Cuda on the far machine.
It was found that there were several different versions of cuda installed. I removed them all except 11.1 that was left. Everything then was built with no problems.